# Preventing Mathematica from simplifying numbers under the root?

Tags: output-formatting

Is there a way to prevent Mathematica from simplifying numbers under the root?

Consider the following example:

```
a = 48^(1/3)
```

The standard output will be:

```
2 * 6^(1/3)
```

But what I want it to remain as it is for the output:

```
48^(1/3)
```

Here is more elaborate example:

```
Ldot := Vvap/Sv
Lstar = ((48 \[Eta])/(\[Rho] g Sv) Ldot)^(1/3)
```

What I want is to simplify everything, except (48)^(1/3).
For example:

```
 Lstar // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm
```

yields:

[image]

Which is good except the fact that I want `(48)^(1/3)` to remain as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
HoldForm[48^(1/3)]
```

for display purposes. But this expression cannot be calculated with. The right solution depends on *what you actually want to achieve*.

There is also `Inactive`/`Inactivate`, which can be calculated with in some cases.

Comment: I've updated the post with the more elaborate example. Thanks!